# Не могу понять в чем ошибка моей программы

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "eng");
    int S = 0;
    float U = 0, V = 0;
    for (int i = 1; S < i;)
    {
        U = floor(rand());
        V = floor(rand());
        S = pow(U, 2) + pow(V, 2);
        if ((S>0) &&(S<1))
        {
            break;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    cout << U << endl;
    cout << V << endl;
    cout << S << endl;
    float x = U * ((-2*log(S))/S);
    cout << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

В ответе генерирует одни и те же числа в U и V как это исправить??

Comment: ошибка в том, что ты не умеешь пользоваться `rand` :)  rand()  генерирует случайное число один раз, при первом запуске программы. В дальнейшем, сколько не запускай эту программу, сгенерированное число останется одним и тем же.......... какие числа ты там хочешь генерировать?

Comment: Для начала прочтите `man 3 rand`, затем (если вопросы еще останутся) можете попечатать `U` и `V`, получаемые  в цикле. Суть вашей ошибки в том, что у вас всегда цикл исполняется 5 раз (вероятность, что результат `rand()` 2 раза подряд будет равен нулю тоже равна 0), следовательно и значения переменных будут одними и теми же.

Comment: У вас тут ужас в каждой строчке. Какой смысл условия выхода `S < i`? Зачем вы округляете случайное число до целого? Почему для возведения в квадрат используете ужасно медленный `pow`? У вас `S` — целое число, почему вы надеетесь, что оно будет между нулём и единицей, не включая концы. И т. д. Если вы пытаетесь получить нормально распределённое случайное число по алгоритму Бокса-Мюллера, скопируйте лучше его из википедии.

Comment: я понимаю я только начинаю изучать С++ потому не знаю всех фишек по типу медленного pow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `rand()` генерирует псевдослучайные числа, поэтому добавь строку `srand(time(NULL) )`  в начало кода.  Возможно понадобиться библиотека `time. h`,  но она должна быть встроена в `iostream`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
     srand(time(0));
}
```